# How to define a constructor to call it for each array?

Tags: java, constructor

I have class PERSON and BOUNCYHOUSE which are combined in main method class PARTNERLAB. 
I have to add people to the bouncyhouse based on weight limit and if one bouncy house is full, move on to the next. 
I get an error that looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
        The constructor BouncyHouse() is undefined

        at PartnerLab1.main(PartnerLab1.java:17)
```

How do I define BouncyHouse?

Here's my code:
PARTNER:

```
public class Person {     //encapsulated class the has name and weight

    private String name;
    private int personWeight;

    public Person(String name, int personWeight){  //two argument constructor thta takes in the name and weight and sets both attributes accordingly
        this.name= name;
        this.personWeight= personWeight;
    }

    public String getName()   //get name
    {
        return this.name;    
    }

    public int getWeight()   //get weight
    {
        return this.personWeight;
    }

    public String getInfo(){   //return all info
        return "Name: " + this.name +
                "\n Person's weight: "+ this.personWeight; 
    }
```

BOUNCYHOUSE

```
import java.util.*;


public class BouncyHouse {   //encapsulated class with weight limit and total current weight with all occupants in the bouncy house

    private int weightLimit;
    private int totalCurrentWeight;
    private ArrayList <Person> occupants;

    public BouncyHouse(int weightLimit, int totalCurrentWeight, ArrayList<Person> occupants){  //no arguments construction that sets the variable to a default value of 0
        this.weightLimit= 0;
        this.totalCurrentWeight= 0;
        this.occupants = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setWeightLimit(int weightLimit)  //sets weight limit
    {
        this.weightLimit = weightLimit;
    }

    public void setTotalCurrentWeight(int totalCurrentWeigth)   //sets total current wieght
    {
        this.totalCurrentWeight = totalCurrentWeigth;
    }



    public String getInfo()   // return all the information about the bouncy house
    {
        StringBuilder personInfo = new StringBuilder();

        for(Person person: occupants)
        {
            personInfo.append(person.getInfo()+",\n\t");
        }
        return "BouncyHouse: " +
                "\nweightLimit=" + this.weightLimit +
                "\ntotalWeight=" + this.totalCurrentWeight +
                "\noccupants= " + personInfo.toString();    //can't do it in one sitting !


    }
    //NEXT: Add a person to the bouncy house 


    public boolean addPerson(Person person)
    {
        // check if weight exceeds the limit
        if((person.getWeight()+totalCurrentWeight) <= weightLimit)
        {
            // add person to occupants list
            this.occupants.add(person);
            // update current total weigh
            this.totalCurrentWeight += person.getWeight();
            return true;
        }
        // else, return false
        return false;
    }
    public Person[] addPerson(Person[] persons)
    {
        Person maxWeightPerson = null;
        int maxWeight = 0;
        for(int i =0; i < persons.length; i++)
        {
            // check if weight exceeds the limit
            if (!addPerson(persons[i]))
            {
                if(persons[i].getWeight() < maxWeight)
                {
                    // remove maxWeightPerson from house and add the current person
                    occupants.remove(maxWeightPerson);
                    totalCurrentWeight -= maxWeightPerson.getWeight();
                    // add person to occupants list
                    this.occupants.add(persons[i]);
                    maxWeight = 0;
                    // find next max weight guy
                    for (Person person : occupants)
                    {
                        if (person.getWeight() > maxWeight)
                        {
                            maxWeight = person.getWeight();
                            maxWeightPerson = person;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(maxWeight < persons[i].getWeight())
                {
                    maxWeight = persons[i].getWeight();
                    maxWeightPerson = persons[i];
                }
            }
        }
        return occupants.toArray(new Person[occupants.size()]);
    }
}
```

PARTNERLAB

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PartnerLab1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String choice, name;
        int weight;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        BouncyHouse[] bouncyHouses = new BouncyHouse[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            bouncyHouses[i] = new BouncyHouse();
            // set weight limits for bouncyHouse
            bouncyHouses[i].setWeightLimit(250);
            // add persons to houses
            do
            {
                System.out.print("Add person to House " + (i + 1) + " (y/q): ");
                choice = in.nextLine();
                if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter name: ");
                    name = in.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Enter weight: ");
                    weight = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
                    if (bouncyHouses[i].addPerson(new Person(name, weight)))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Person added");
                    } else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Person can't be added. Exceeds weight limit.");
                    }
                }
            } while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("q"));
        }
        // display people in houses
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("People in House " + i + 1);
            System.out.println(bouncyHouses[i].getInfo());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a parametrized constructor for your BouncyHouse class so you can't call a no-argument constructor without explicitly defining it in your class.

Answer (score 0):

As per the code you have written in main class, You don't required parametrized constructor into **BouncyHouse** class. You can remove it or in case if you required some where else then add no-argument constructor in **BouncyHouse** class.